# Efficient query to get count

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

I have written a query which returns a count. My question is, is this a efficient query?

attribute_value is of type "longtext" and can have maximum of 5 values. All these attribute values come from a ENUM (5 distinct Strings). Both the tables can grow longer. managed_channel can contain million records and managed_attribute can contains 10 times the size of managed_channel records

Keeping that in mind, will this query work efficiently or I may have to use other techniques (index?) to get the performance up.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as mo_count
FROM managed_channel mo, managed_attribute ma
WHERE  mo.id = ma.mo_id
AND mo.class_type = 3946
AND ma.attribute_type = 4293
AND ma.attribute_value IN ("ILLEGAL_MPS", "ILLEGAL_ID", "ILLEGAL_IP")
```

Comment: BTW, the database is mysql

Comment: The performance of a query like this will depend very much on the indexes you have created. There's no way to judge from this alone what performance is likely to be. In any case, if you want to know the performance, measure it. Anything we suggest will be little more than educated guesswork.

Comment: Can't tell, don't know number of rows, data distribution, indexes etc.

Comment: This could be an answer: yes you could optimize the query: `join`; yes, you could use other techniques: indexes, `explain`.

Comment: @lp_, does the JOIN keyword speed up queries?

Comment: The query itself is as optimized as you can get. I would prefer the ANSI join syntax over this syntax but that's just synthetic sugar. The only way to speed up the query is by using proper indexes like has already been suggested, using proper data types and using a proper model.

Comment: @jarlh: 'could', in general. It reads differently, and without the join you rely on the database engine and its optimizer. Though, mysql would use the same execution plan, so it doesn't really matter here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to return rows but get a count on managed_channel. You have to use the benefit of indexes files.

So you have to have an index on managed_attribute on your whole 3 columns in an order permitting the foreign key to work

```
   ALTER TABLE managed_attribute ADD INDEX (attribute_type, attribute_value, mo_id);
```

and on managed_channel, following the chain

```
   ALTER TABLE managed_channel ADD INDEX(mo_id, class_type);
```

Also you should prefer to count only on the field in your indexes:

```
   SELECT COUNT(mo.mo_id) ...
```

Note: I don't understand why you use LONGTEXT for a field that looks like very short. So you'd rather take a VARCHAR or ENUM type (sorry didn't understand that part)

Comment: Well, the attribute_value in my query wont exceed 5 Strings. The attribute_value in the table could be anything. I have no control over why it is defined as longtext and I cant change it.

Comment: ok so you won't be able to put an index on that column but it doesn't matter